# Scraping images of

Tags: image, xpath, import.io

I'm try to scrape data images from a website using import.io

An example of what I'm trying to scrape can be found at 
http://www.thecar-company.co.uk/used-cars/renault-laguna-1-6-16v-rt-5dr-leamington-spa-201510197972406

It is car trading website. Each car is displayed with a primary image and then a number of additional images. The additional images are displayed as small images (164 x 123). Larger versions of these images(640 x 480) can be viewed by clicking on image.

I've been able to scrape all of the images, but only the small versions. I want to scrape the larger images.

```
**Here is the source code:**
<div id="advertSummaryComponent" class="rzc-advert-summary">
<p class="back"><a href="/used-cars"><span>View all our used cars</span></a>      
</p>
<div class="description">
    <div class="image">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://pictures2.autotrader.co.uk/imgser-uk/servlet/media.jpg?id=c860b3af7b034ef58afe7d98e53eb964&amp;width=640&amp;height=480" alt="RENAULT LAGUNA Hatchback 1.6 16v RT 5dr" id="item-0" />
            <span id="span-0">Click to enlarge</span>
        </div>                      
        <div class="navs"> 
            <ul>
<li><a href="http://pictures2.autotrader.co.uk/imgser-uk/servlet/media.jpg?id=c860b3af7b034ef58afe7d98e53eb964&amp;width=640&amp;height=480" id="nav-0"><img src="http://pictures2.autotrader.co.uk/imgser-uk/servlet/media.jpg?id=c860b3af7b034ef58afe7d98e53eb964&amp;width=164&amp;height=123" alt="RENAULT LAGUNA Hatchback 1.6 16v RT 5dr" /></a></li><li><a href="http://pictures2.autotrader.co.uk/imgser-uk/servlet/media.jpg?id=9f1012cb998d4b18a70d8e526ccac5bf&amp;width=640&amp;height=480" id="nav-1"><img src="http://pictures2.autotrader.co.uk/imgser-uk/servlet/media.jpg?id=9f1012cb998d4b18a70d8e526ccac5bf&amp;width=164&amp;height=123" alt="RENAULT LAGUNA Hatchback 1.6 16v RT 5dr" /></a></li><li><a href="http://pictures2.autotrader.co.uk/imgser-uk/servlet/media.jpg?id=2c95074384d84ec8a7919ff644677801&amp;width=640&amp;height=480" id="nav-2"><img src="http://pictures2.autotrader.co.uk/imgser-uk/servlet/media.jpg?id=2c95074384d84ec8a7919ff644677801&amp;width=164&amp;height=123" alt="RENAULT LAGUNA Hatchback 1.6 16v RT 5dr" /></a></li><li><a href="http://pictures2.autotrader.co.uk/imgser-uk/servlet/media.jpg?id=0e957848e1b74f67ac6e1d69c5f5e2cc&amp;width=640&amp;height=480" id="nav-3"><img src="http://pictures2.autotrader.co.uk/imgser-uk/servlet/media.jpg?id=0e957848e1b74f67ac6e1d69c5f5e2cc&amp;width=164&amp;height=123" alt="RENAULT LAGUNA Hatchback 1.6 16v RT 5dr" /></a></li><li><a href="http://pictures2.autotrader.co.uk/imgser-uk/servlet/media.jpg?id=3746daefe8504eaab8ad1ba59de74a5e&amp;width=640&amp;height=480" id="nav-4"><img src="http://pictures2.autotrader.co.uk/imgser-uk/servlet/media.jpg?id=3746daefe8504eaab8ad1ba59de74a5e&amp;width=164&amp;height=123" alt="RENAULT LAGUNA Hatchback 1.6 16v RT 5dr" /></a></li> 
            </ul>    
        </div>
```

**The absolute XPath is:**
/html/body/table/tbody/tr[205]/td[2]/span[2]/a

I'm trying to get the relative XPath
I'm trying to creating a relative XPath, but have been unsuccessful.

Can anyone help?

Comment: "relative xpath"? Relative to **WHAT**?

Comment: _“It is car trading website”_ – use their API. If they don’t provide one, stop stealing their content. (Or do you have their explicit permission for scraping?)

Comment: This project is for this car trading company. It will also included other car trading companies, all of whom have signed an agreement to allow the content to be used.

Comment: And they don;t have an API.

Answer (score 0):

How about just using the absolute XPath to the image in the box?

`//*[@id="cboxLoadedContent"]/img`